# Shared hosting, define a new root

Tags: php

A client is using shared hosting.  Lets say his primary domain is maindomain.com.  When he buys a new domain name, he creates a folder on his hosting account and points the new domain to it.  But, when including a file,

> include("/inc/defines.inc.php");

it's looking in the inc folder under maindomain.com, not under the new domain's folder.

How do I set this up so his new domain is viewed as the root when a viewer reaches the page?
There are a lot of includes in this site.  But, if he creates a new folder, under the new domain, it get's a little difficult getting to it without all the ../ ../'s

I hope I explained this well.  I'm having a hard time following it myself...

Answer (score 0):

You can use realpath(), and the **FILE** constant to obtain the root of the current script. Additionally, you can get paths using getcwd(), or $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].  Pick the one that is most reliable for you. My personal favorite is the first example.

A good example would be:

```
// Method #1    
// Base path is from the path where the current file this is inside is located
$root = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
echo $root;

// Method #2
// Base path is from the Current Working Directory
$root = rtrim(getcwd(), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
echo $root;

// Method #3
// Base path is the server root directory for this site.
$path = str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$path = str_replace('/',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$path);
$root = rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
echo $root;
```

Once you have selected a method, it's just a simple matter of preceding the path like so :

```
// removed the first slash as I append that in all the above examples.
include($root . "inc/defines.inc.php");
```